# Does TimesTen support high availability? If so, how do I configure it?

Tags: high-availability, timesten

I am considering using the TimesTen In-Memory Database for my application but I need high-availability. Can TimesTen provide this and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, TimesTen has excellent high availability capabilities.

For TimesTen Classic you can configure high availability using TimesTen active/standby pair replication. Details here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/timesten-18.1/TTREP/toc.htm

For TimesTen Scaleout, high availability is automatic and is based on the configured K- factor for the database (>1 gives you HA). Details here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/timesten-18.1/TTGRD/overview.htm#TTGRD118